# Visual Studio 2012 SSRS connection to Claims based SharePoint site?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, authentication, sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity

I have a sharePoint Web Application using claims based.

On My development Client (Visual studio 2012 and business Intelligence 2012) I'm trying to make a connection to a sharePoint list with the user/password it's telling me **Forbidden 403**.  I've also tried integrated but it tells me that is integrated not supported for this connection type (XML and/or SharePoint List)

**Is there any way to connect to this SharePoint 2010 list under Claims based from SSRS 2012 Dev client?**

I'm sure I'll have another set of issues once the report is deployed. Like if I can get a native SSRS server (not SP integrated) to use Claims based.. seperate questions I know, but will it be possible (thinking ahead here) to have an SPO 2013 site on the cloud displaying local SSRS report (not hosted in SharePoint)  within SP webparts **without a prompt for security**?

Comment: Have you tried making a simpler connection using MS Access to see if you have the permission?

Comment: yes, I've been able to connect to a list on the same farm in a web app with just NTML.  The issue appears to be claims based.